# Angular pass object from template to controller as function parameter

Tags: angularjs

In my angular page I have multi city (combo box) and after change the city
I get relevant streets.

This is my template

```
<ui-select on-select="cityChange($item, siteService.userObject.p1_street, siteService.availableStreets.p1_streets)" ng-model="siteService.userObject.p1_city" >
</ui-select>
```

And this is my controller function

```
 $scope.cityChange = function (city, street, _streets) {

        street = null;
        _streets = [];
        personalService.getStreets(city.id).then(function (data) {
            _streets = data;
            console.log(_streets) //has data
            console.log(siteService.availableStreets.p1_streets) //empty
        });
    }
```

My problem is that on the controller function the reference does not to the main object, just to stand alone object

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `siteService` is a service. If so, your code needs refactoring.

You cannot refer to a service on the template unless you reference it to it's scope ( which is an anti-pattern and not a good idea ).

Comment: $scope.siteService = siteService; in the controller reference to service, the object is for all the pages that's why the object is in the service